# Showing 2 tables on 1 page

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I have 2 grid-tables on my page. When I want to load them both, the first grid-table gets loaded, but the second is not. How can I fix this?

Here is the table for my first grid-table:

```
<table id="employee_grid" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

There is the second grid table:

```
<table id="employee_grid2" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

As you can see I changed the ID for the second table.

There is the javascript for the first table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#employee_grid').DataTable({
            "bprocessing" : true,
            "serverSide" : true,
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "post1.php",
                "type" : "POST",
                "error" : function() {
                    $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display", "none");
                }
            },
            "columnDefs" : [{
                "targets" : 0,
                "render" : function(data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="http://www.example.com/' + data + '">Link</a>';
                }
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the javascript for the second table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#employee_grid2').DataTable({
            "bprocessing" : true,
            "serverSide" : true,
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "post2.php",
                "type" : "POST",
                "error" : function() {
                    $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display", "none");
                }
            },
            "columnDefs" : [{
                "targets" : 0,
                "render" : function(data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a href="http://www.example.com/' + data + '">Link</a>';
                }
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, also the only thing I changed in the second javascript code = `#employee_grid2`. I think this should be enough to run both javascript codes on 1 page, but the second table dont gets filled.

How can I fix this?

Comment: As well as changing the jQuery selector to `'#employee_grid2'`, you also changed the AJAX URL to `"post2.php"` in your second piece of JS. But that’s probably what you want anyway. Still, that could be causing the problem if the page `post2.php` was broken and not returning data – have you checked whether that’s the case?

Comment: Currently post1.php and post2.php has exactly the same codes. If I get this step working I am gonna change the script for post2.php